# has.key method in hash package of R not storing string key properly

Tags: r, twitter, hash, hashmap

I am trying to create a [hashmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/hash.pdf) in R with key as screen name of a twitter user(string) and value as the number of his tweets I have crawled (integer).

```
user_count_map <- hash()
i=1
while(i<= num_tweets){
screen_name <- tweets_df[i,]$screenName
#print (screen_name)
#str(screen_name)
if(has.key(screen_name,user_count_map)==TRUE){
    count <- user_count_map$screen_name
    user_count_map$screen_name <- (count +1)
} else {
   user_count_map$screen_name <- 1
}
i = i+1
}
```

There are around 17k tweets in the dataframe tweets_df (so num_tweets ~ 17k) and there are certainly users for whom I have collected more than 1 tweet. The problem is that the 'if' statement is never executed and the control *always* passes to the 'else' statement. After the execution of this code, the length of this map is 1. Here is the output of keys() and values() method :-

```
values(user_count_map)
screen_name: 1

keys(user_count_map)
'screen_name'
```

Here is one output of str(screen_name) :-

```
chr "Ixxxxxxxxa"
```

Clearly there is a hashing issue in with how screen_name variable is resolved/hashed and stored in the map. What can I do to rectify this? I am fairly new to R. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the hash elements incorrectly. Your statement
    `user_count_map$screen_name <- 1`
gives the key "screen_name" the value 1.  It is not evaluating the variable
called screen_name.  It is using the literal string "screen_name". 
Instead,  What you need is to use is
`user_count_map[screen_name] <- 1`.
This will evaluate the variable `screen_name` and use the value as the hash key.

Your entire code segment should read:

```
user_count_map <- hash()
i=1
while(i <= num_tweets){
   screen_name <- tweets_df[i,]$screenName
   if(has.key(screen_name,user_count_map)==TRUE) {
        count <- user_count_map[screen_name]
        user_count_map[screen_name] <- (count +1)
   } else {
        user_count_map[screen_name] <- 1
   }
   i = i+1
}
```

Comment: Using '[' doesn't work either, using '[[' operator does. I am trying to figure out why. Thanks

Comment: Odd.  "[" worked for me on single test examples,  but I did not have your full data frame to test on.